# Logging in with requests post

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I have used request post function many times before. I don't know why but now I can not log in to one web site:

```
   # Import
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Core settings
HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

s = Session()
response = s.get("https://suite.searchmetrics.com/en/auth/login", headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
redirect_url = soup.select('input[id="id_redirect_data"]')[0].get("value")
data = {"redirect_url": redirect_url,
        "mail": "aaa@gmail.com",
        "password": "abcfeFD"}
s.post("https://suite.searchmetrics.com/en/auth/authenticate", data=data, headers=HEADERS)
```

Then when I try:

```
content_url = "https://suite.searchmetrics.com/en/research?url=wsj.com"
response = s.get(content_url, headers=HEADERS)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
print(soup1.prettify())
```

I can not find hash tags that belong to highchart

Comment: You should submit your data to `"/en/auth/authenticate"`

Comment: I changed it to suite.searchmetrics.com/en/auth/authenticate, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: It works for me. Can you update your post with your current code?

Comment: I updated the code, but there was not much of a change

Comment: What error or response do you get?

Comment: When I try to get the content using session.get(), I can not get the content that appears after you log in

Comment: `s.get()`  gives me the whole page

Comment: You won't get exactly the same html with `requests` because some content is generated by js. But how do you check if you are logged in? I get `True` with `"You are successfully logged in." in r.text` (`r` is the post request) using your code as it is.

Comment: Yeah exactly, you are right thank your for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you define redirect_url but don't actually use it. You do use redirect_name but don't define it anywhere. Might that be your problem?